# How to install chrome extension on chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Some chrome extension doesn't work on chromium. 
This for example: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#5d81304a17cf7ac2887484f730fbd2b01e51e166

How can I get it to work on chromium ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can successfully load it (Chromium 18.0.1025.151, Ubuntu 11.10).
I only encountered one problem, when I literally dragged the code to [`nano`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano_%28text_editor%29): Some newlines were truncated, causing code to be commented. Check whether you correctly copy-pasted the code.

[image]

When the extension loads, but "nothing happens", check the console for errors. The console for the background page can be opened by [following these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/938089?google-chrome-extension-logging-from-background-js).